# How to make an Indicator update only once and never change the appearance?

Tags: mql4

Is there a way to let the indicator update the chart once, and for the subsequent, it will remember the old results rather than update every tick or candle?

I am asking this question since I only let the `start()` run once with the following code:

```
bool first = True;              // .DEF GLOBAL lock

int start(){
    if (  first ){              // .TST ?
          first = False;        // .SET ! ( lock forever )
          ...                   // .RUN my code here
          ..
          .
          }
    ...
    ..
    .
    return( 0 );
    }
```

and I set the indicator using buffer. After every candle update, the indicator moves to another candle beside (since the buffer array has updated)..
I would like them to stay at that candle forever. What should I do?

Comment: is this javascript code?

Comment: it is not clear whether you want to calculate everything just once or not, and why. if only once - you may use script instead of indicator. if you need access to buffers - ea/ind will call your indicator, and return EMPTY_VALUE for the bars after the the 0-bar when you started. so it doesnt look to be a good approach also. maybe you could describe the problem better to understand how to help you

Answer (score 0):

### Such idea is perfectly doable:

Details depend on your actual use-case.

Given a **`bool first = True; // .DEF GLOBAL lock`** is being used on a global-scope, the locking mechanism is clear & fully under your control. Not the case for addressing the once pre-computed ( and pre-stored ) values, injected into the **`IndicatorBuffer[]`**-s, which is subject of the reversed-TimeBased-shifting, so that your most recent value, stored in the cell-index **`[0]`**, will upon each **`aNewBarEVENT`** arrival grow old and shift to the "left" ( in time ), becoming `[++i]` upon each such new candle beginning.

### Is this a problem?

If yes, one may change the methods for `iCustom(...)`-based indicator-value inspections.

It would be quite enough to freeze the time on a global-scope register or use a smart access-index function:

```
bool first = True;                    // .DEF GLOBAL lock

double iCustomFrozenInTime( const int cellINDEX = 0 ){
    static int Bars_onFirst = Bars;   // .DEF STATIC first_Bars
    if (  first ){
               Bars_onFirst = Bars;   // .SET STATIC first_Bars
       }
    return( iCustom( _Symbol,
                     PERIOD_CURRENT,
                     ...,
                     cellINDEX + ( Bars - Bars_onFirst )
                     )
            );
    }

int start(){ 
    if (  first ){                    // .TST ?
          iCustomFrozenInTime();      // .SET   ( Bars_onFirst )
          first = False;              // .SET ! ( lock forever )
          ...                         // .RUN my code here
          ..
          .
          }
    ...
    ..
    .                                 // .GET values literally "Frozen in Time"
    aFrozenCELL_0 = iCustomFrozenInTime( 0 )
    aFrozenCELL_1 = iCustomFrozenInTime( 1 );
    aFrozenCELL_2 = iCustomFrozenInTime( 2 );
    return( 0 );
    }
```